# Error connecting to Zookeeper with Spark Streaming Structured

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

My `Spark Streaming Structured` keeps disconnecting from Zookeeper when trying to read from a `Kafka`topic:

```
WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker [zk host]:2181 disconnected
```

When I check the ZK logs, I see this error being prompted all the time:

```
Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException
```

I´m running on Cloudera 5.11 with Spark 2.1, these are my SBT libraries:

```
val sparkVer = "2.1.0"
Seq(
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % "provided" withSources(),
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVer % "provided",
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVer % "provided",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" % sparkVer
```

)

This is my submit command:

```
# Set KAFKA to 0.10 see (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/KafkaConsumer-subscribe-0-9-vs-0-10-in-Structured-streaming/td-p/60161)
export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10 
spark2-submit  --class myMainClass --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0 myapp.jar topic2345 [zk host 1]:2181,[zk host 2]:2181
```

And this is the code creating the stream:

```
  private def createKafkaStrem(spark: SparkSession, args: Array[String]) = {
     spark.readStream
     .format("kafka")
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", args(1))
     .option("subscribe", args(0))
     .load()
 }
```

EDIT: After activating the DEBUG ouput, this is the complete error stack:

```
java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:83)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:323)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:183)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:974)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSource$$fetchLatestOffsets$1.apply(KafkaSource.scala:374)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSource$$fetchLatestOffsets$1.apply(KafkaSource.scala:372)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaSource.scala:442)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1.apply(KafkaSource.scala:441)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1.apply(KafkaSource.scala:441)
at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaSource.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSource$$fetchLatestOffsets(KafkaSource.scala:372)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$initialPartitionOffsets$1.apply(KafkaSource.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$initialPartitionOffsets$1.apply(KafkaSource.scala:138)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.initialPartitionOffsets$lzycompute(KafkaSource.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.initialPartitionOffsets(KafkaSource.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.getOffset(KafkaSource.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:391)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:391)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:265)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$9.apply(StreamExecution.scala:390)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$9.apply(StreamExecution.scala:388)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch(StreamExecution.scala:388)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$populateStartOffsets(StreamExecution.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:260)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:265)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:187)
18/03/21 10:47:27 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Node -2 disconnected.
18/03/21 10:47:27 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker [zk host]:2181 disconnected
18/03/21 10:47:27 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Sending metadata request {topics=[topic2345]} to node -1
18/03/21 10:47:27 DEBUG network.Selector: Connection with /[zk host] disconnected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka.bootstrap.servers` takes a list of Kafka brokers, not a Zookeeper quorum.

The "new" Kafka Consumer API does not use a Zookeeper connection string

Comment: Jeez, I am really used to using ZK whenever I need to consume from a Kafka topic... Really hard to make this setup work, thanks!

Comment: `kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper` will warn you that Zookeeper connection is deprecated in the newer releases of Kafka